# Page redirected/ merged. Can this detected with GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This page for example:
https://www.facebook.com/202344606451254

Actually points to:
https://www.facebook.com/23766404924

Is there any way to detect this using GraphAPI?

GraphAPI queries with the old id, eg

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/202344606451254/feed?access_token=xxx
```

will return no data

In case the links change in the future: API queries of the respective IDs show the first is "wpp plc" and the second is "wpp". The title of the first link says these ids have been merged.

Comment: The first link you posted does not seem to be linked at all with the second.  The first is an automatically generated page that is not managed, the second is an actual page managed by the business.

Graph calls to the first page don't appear to fail, there just isn't any data associated with the first page...

Comment: API queries of the respective IDs shows the first is "wpp plc" and the second is "wpp". The title of the first link says these ids have been merged

Comment: Oh, weird...  That is not what it was doing for me this morning when I tested the links you posted.  The first link just landed on the old auto-generated page.  Now it is functioning for me as you describe.  Probably a delayed replication issue across Facebook's servers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this:

`/v2.3/202344606451254?fields=best_page`

I'm not sure exactly what circumstances will cause that to work, but I tested it a little on Graph Explorer.  It seems to be a field that will be filled in if the user should be using a better page than the one they tried to access:

The page you mention in your first link returns a structure that contains information about the second link.

The page in the second link does not return any data for that field.  I tested several pages I manage, and they also return no data for that field.

Comment: Thank you. I was working on the assumption all fields would be returned by default, guess that's not the case

Comment: No, it's not.  For every edge there is a default set of fields that are returned if you don't specify fields, but almost every edge has fields that are not returned by default and need to be specified.

Glad I could help!  =)